# If you store a personal spell in a wand, can you then target other creatures with that spell?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, magic-items

I'm aware that you can't brew a potion from any spell with "range: personal, target: you", since it is restricted to:

> any 3rd-level or lower spell that you know and that targets one or more creatures

[and](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm#creatingPotions)

> Spells with a range of personal cannot be made into potions.

However, staves and wands do not have this restriction:

> To activate a wand, a character must hold it in hand (or whatever passes for a hand, for nonhumanoid creatures) and point it in the general direction of the target or area.

So, what if you point your wand of *true strike* at somebody else? Does the spell then affect them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. Nothing in the [wand](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wands.htm) rules notes that anything about the spells stored in the wand changes. While the list of spells in the wands are all spells that can target other creatures, there is no reason why a wand cannot cast a spell of "personal" range on the person who can trigger the spell.

A feat or PrC is needed for the wand to behaved differently. Extending personal spells to others can be done through the Spellguard of Silverymoon PrC (Player's Guide to Faerûn).

Comment: Strictly speaking the claim that "Nothing in the wand rules notes that anything about the spells stored in the wand changes," is incorrect, at least without *Rules Compendium*. Under the original rules, activating a spell in a Wand was *always* a standard action, regardless of how long the original spell took. *Rules Compendium* fixed this oversight, however.

Answer (score 19):

No, it does not.

Activating a wand is a Spell Triggered<sup>[D20SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemBasics.htm#spellTrigger)</sup> action.  That means it is cast as if the user of the wand had cast the spell.  It still has a range of personal and only affects the creature who activated the wand.

Answer (score 5):

You could store spell in wands and then let others use it.  Players in my group do this the thief carries around a wand with true strike, and usually a healing scroll in case the healers go down.  Just make sure their Use Magical Device is way high.