# Is there a Potion of Magic Circle against Evil?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I know that you can brew a potion for any 3rd-level or lower spell that targets one or more creatures : [If you store a personal spell in a wand, can you then target other creatures with that spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4559/1129).

The Magic Circle against Evil has no target, but the area specified mentions a touched creature.

```
Level:      Clr 3, Good 3, Pal 3, Sor/Wiz 3
Components:     V, S, M/DF
Casting Time:   1 standard action
Range:  Touch
Area:   10-ft.-radius emanation from touched creature
Duration:   10 min./level
Saving Throw:   Will negates (harmless)
Spell Resistance:   No; see text
```

So can there be a potion of Magic Circle against Evil? And what will it do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is a potion of Magic Circle against Evil in the DMG.

It would work fine with the first kind of casting (the emanation of protection vs evil) and would move with the target as is normal for the spell.

If you made a "second kind of casting" MCvE potion, it would still work like the spell, go back and read it carefully - it would need to be drunk by a spellcaster one round away from casting a summoning/binding spell, not by the prospective bound creature. The second kind of casting overrides several of the spell's normal parameters in its description.  It might be helpful in terms of not depleting a mage's third level spell slot right before summoning something touchy, but not as a "bad guy trap."

Comment: It's also in the d20srd -> http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/potionsAndOils.htm  A roll of 81 in the medium column

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

The potion exists and it's even on the list of sample potion you can found on the Player's Handbook. In a random treasure you'll get it with a 81 on a medium item roll or a 47 on a major item roll.

The potion generates an emanation centered on the imbiber. Every creature within 10-ft. from the imbeber is automatically affected by a **Protection from Evil**<sup>[d20SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/protectionFromEvil.htm)</sup> effect and non-good creatures cannot come closer than 10-ft. to the imbiber (unless they have Spell Resistance, in which case a check is required).

**Magic Circle against Evil**<sup>[d20SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicCircleAgainstEvil.htm)</sup> has an alternative usage that must be decided prior to casting. You focus it inward in order to trap a non-good creature that you are going to call with a **Conjuration (Calling)** spell in the following round.
So, even *Magic Circle against Evil (inward)* potions could be created (whether it is focused inward or outward must be decided as the potion is being brewed). Such a potion should be drank by the summoner one round prior to the calling spell.

Comment: Which book and page has the sample treasure as that potion?

Comment: Don't have the page right now. The book should be the **Dungeon Master Guide**, under the magic item section.

Comment: Right now, I could direct you to [this link](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/potionsAndOils.htm) which contains an extract of the DMG.

Comment: Couldn't find it in DMG, but the website was perfect.

Comment: Also, I couldn't find anywhere, where it was stated "Once creatures are affected, they don't need to stay within 10 ft. of the imbiber."

Comment: I actually inferred it from **Magic Circle against Evil**'s area and effects. But I now realise that the spell's _intention_ could be different: it may work like a 10-ft. aura centered on the target. But this leaves a question open: what happens to the circle when the target moves?

Comment: Yes, I don't think it is black and white. I will need to have a think about it further. I do like your original answer, but as you said, it all depends on the intention of the author.

Comment: I've just posted a question. Let's see if other people would help us making it clear.

Comment: I believe this is an incorrect interpretation of both versions of the spell.

Comment: Re-reading the spell I found that @mxyzplk is right. Accroding to sites' guidelines, is it better to edit my answer or deleting it?

Comment: @Erik Burigo -- Either alternative is fine, as long as the answer is complete and correct, at least for users who don't have edit permissions on other users' yet. Just make sure you're bringing something to the answer that isn't there already... Better formatting, more information, "better" writeup, whatever.

Comment: Edited in order to reflect the corrections pointed out by @mxyzplk.

Answer (score 3):

Potion would exist.

But I would limit it to the emanation from the drinker version of the spell. The drinker gets +2 AC, +2 against spells from evil creatures, and protection from possession, and a ten feet area of protection against evil creatures.

But! read carefully protection from evil, the part where you can't be touched by evil creatures only concerns **exteriors and elementals**. So the ten feet zone of protection only concerns such creatures.

for the drinker to be able to draw a magic circle on the ground to trap an summoned creature by drinking a potion makes little sense to me.

Comment: sorry, I must say I stick to 3rd edition, maybe in 3.5 they wrote something else. But something else would seem unlogical to me.

Comment: **A note for those unfamiliar with the "exteriors" term**: In certain translations of D&D, "exteriors" was the word for the "outsider" creature type. Fractal is not describing a spell that protects against lead paint and shoddy weatherboarding.